# How to enable back TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 on nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, tls1.1, tls1.0

My nginx confid files looks like:

```
 server {
   listen          80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name hostserver.ru www.hostserver.ru;
   return 301 https://hostserver.ru$request_uri;

   server_tokens off;
  }

 server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   server_name     hostserver.ru www.hostserver.ru;

   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostserver.ru/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostserver.ru/privkey.pem;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
   ssl_session_tickets off;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-R$
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
   ssl_stapling on;
   ssl_stapling_verify on;

   root /var/www/html;
   index index.html index.htm;
   server_tokens off;

   ... some location stuff...
}
```

Ufortunatelly, TLS1.2 not supported by Android 4.0-4.3 and I've chanched config:

```
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

But after using [SSLTest](http://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) it shows me report that TLS1 and TLS1.1 are not supported.

Did I missed smth to change in config files?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I've checked certificates by command:

```
openssl s_client -tls1 (and so on) -connect example.org:443 < /dev/null
```

and certificate enabled for each protocol.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making those changes?

Comment: @Rob Yes! I restarted nginx and whole ubuntu server - no effect

Comment: You might want to check which ciphers work with TLSv1 and TLSv1.1. Testing my site, GCM ciphers are listed against only TLSv1.2 - you may want to add some more ciphers. E.g. `ssl_ciphers             "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";`

Comment: @RichardSmith you're right! Would you post your comment as answer?

Comment: you can list SSL ciphers using `nmap -script ssl-enum-ciphers -p PORT HOSTNAME`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know which ciphers work with TLSv1 and TLSv1.1. But I notice from testing sites with SSLTest, that the GCM ciphers are listed against TLSv1.2 only.

You may need to use a more inclusive list of ciphers.

For example:

```
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
```

Comment: Yep! I've changed list of my cyphers (there were only supported TLS1.2). For newbies in this question I can recommend https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ - I had 
smth like "Modern" type.

Comment: I have the same issue (nginx 1.18.0, OpenSSL 1.1.1f) and wrote `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers "ALL";`, then restarted nginx, but it's not making any difference. SSLTest still shows support fon TLSv1.2 only.

Comment: Turns out, the OpenSSL configuration `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` also plays a role in this, and can forbid protocols (and probably ciphers) even if nginx is requesting them explicitly. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568390/14637 whith helped solve the problem.

Comment: Add `@SECLEVEL=1` in the cipher list: `ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:@SECLEVEL=1";` see https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html for levels

Comment: @JPelletier The only one that worked for me! You just saved my day!

Comment: That testing was no coincidence -- AEAD ciphers (GCM, CCM, and ChaCha/Poly) were a [new feature in TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-1.2) that did not exist in earlier versions (and they are the _only_ ciphers in TLS1.3 but that was 2021, after you posted this)

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 22.04, getting TLS 1.0/1.1 to work is a massive pain, as it appears that Ubuntu's openssl 3.0 build doesn't include TLS 1.0/1.1 support at all.

I was able to get it to work by:

1. Building openssl 1.1.1 branch from [source](https://www.openssl.org/source/)
2. Building nginx from [source](https://nginx.org/download/) after uninstalling libssl-dev so it finds the local built openssl - and make sure to enable the [modules](http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html) you need
3. Updating the openssl [config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568390/14637)
4. Updating the Nginx [config](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&version=1.17.7&config=old&openssl=1.1.1k&hsts=false&ocsp=false&guideline=5.6)
5. Updating my systemd service to use the local nginx build

Caveat emptor. Keep in mind that if you do this you won't get automatic security updates.

Answer (score 0):

On a Debian bookworm server, I had to do the following to enable TLS 1.0 (for Debian squeeze clients):

- configure `ssl_ciphers DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0;` in nginx (and `ssl_protocols`)
- reconfigure my letsencrypt certificate with the certbot `--key-type rsa` flag

I had assumed that `ssl_ciphers ALL;` would enable all the ciphers, but according to [the OpenSSL manpage](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html) that is not the case.

Since [Certbot 2.0](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ecdsa-certificates-by-default-and-other-upcoming-changes-in-certbot-2-0/177013), the certificates are ECDSA by default so some RSA ciphers don't work.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and nginx 1.18. The SECLEVEL=0 instead of SECLEVEL=1 made it work. Together with https://stackoverflow.com/a/61568390/14637 . So no need to recompile openssl or nginx.