# OpenSSL v1.1.1 Ubuntu 20 TLSv1 - no protocols available

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

In Ubuntu 20.04, through a VPN, I can no longer access a server, which uses the TLSv1 protocol.

In Ubuntu 18.04, it was working.

First I connect to the VPN via SNX and then I use a program that accesses the server.

I did some tests with openssl to highlight this problem. Is it possible to solve this? I believe that my problem may have to do with the same reported at https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4097.

I think [OpenSSL v1.1.1 ssl_choose_client_version unsupported protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058362/openssl-v1-1-1-ssl-choose-client-version-unsupported-protocol) has to do with my problem, but it's different because it doesn't have the problem "no protocols available".

When I test with openssl, I get the error "**unsupported protocol**", but when I test with openssl **forcing TLSv1** I get the error "**no protocols available**".

Details of the tests:

**Ubuntu 18.04:**

```
Package: openssl
-> Version: 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1 ~ 18.04.5

openssl s_client -connect host: port
-> works - TLSv1 ("SSL-Session: Protocol: TLSv1.").

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1
-> works - TLSv1 ("SSL-Session: Protocol: TLSv1.").

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1_1
-> 139786161414592: error: 1425F102: SSL routines: ssl_choose_client_version: unsupported protocol: ../ ssl / statem / statem_lib.c: 1907:

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1_2
-> 139786161414592: error: 1425F102: SSL routines: ssl_choose_client_version: unsupported protocol: ../ ssl / statem / statem_lib.c: 1907:
```

**Ubuntu 20.04:**

```
Package: openssl
-> Version: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2

openssl s_client -connect host: port
-> 140253162648896: error: 1425F102: SSL routines: ssl_choose_client_version: unsupported protocol: ../ ssl / statem / statem_lib.c: 1941:

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1
-> 139722831217984: error: 141E70BF: SSL routines: tls_construct_client_hello: no protocols available: ../ ssl / statem / statem_clnt.c: 1112:

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1_1
-> 139923839911232: error: 141E70BF: SSL routines: tls_construct_client_hello: no protocols available: ../ ssl / statem / statem_clnt.c: 1112:

openssl s_client -connect host: port -tls1_2
-> 139862992581952: error: 1425F102: SSL routines: ssl_choose_client_version: unsupported protocol: ../ ssl / statem / statem_lib.c: 1941:
```

**Ubuntu 18.04 - Successfully detailed connection**

```
my@machine: ~ $ openssl s_client -connect my.domain: 9023 -tls1
CONNECTED (00000005)
depth = 2 C = XX, O = XXXXXX, OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
verify error: num = 19: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
 0 s: C = XX, ST = XX, L = XXXXXX, O = XXXXXXXX, OU = XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX, CN = xxx.com
   i: C = XX, O = XXXXXXXX., OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
 1 s: C = XX, O = XXXXXXXX., OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
   i: C = XX, O = XXXXXXXX., OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
 2 s: C = XX, O = XXXXXXXX., OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
   i: C = XX, O = XXXXXXXX., OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXX vX
---
Server certificate
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----
(...)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=X = XX, ST = XX, L = XXXXXX, O = XXXXXXX, OU = XXXXXXXX, CN = mydomain.com

issuer=C = XX, O = XXXXXXXXXX, OU = ICP-XX, CN = AC XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4604 bytes and written 449 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol: TLSv1
    Cipher: AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1588445847
    Timeout: 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

**Ubuntu 20.04 - Detailed unsuccessful connection:**

```
my@machine: ~ / Documents / $ openssl s_client -connect my.domain: 9023
CONNECTED (00000003)
139912319178048: error: 1425F102: SSL routines: ssl_choose_client_version: unsupported protocol: ../ ssl / statem / statem_lib.c: 1941:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4545 bytes and written 309 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

my@machine: ~ / Documents / study $ openssl s_client -connect my.domain: 9023 -tls1
CONNECTED (00000003)
140581447836992: error: 141E70BF: SSL routines: tls_construct_client_hello: no protocols available: ../ ssl / statem / statem_clnt.c: 1112:
-
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've just solved my problem with - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level

Just quoting this link:

You need to add this to the beginning of your config file:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

And then this to the end:

```
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = ssl_default_sect

[ssl_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

The comment on the above link said:

```
Note that if you prefer you can make changes to a local copy of the config file, and then ensure your process is started with the environment variable OPENSSL_CONF defined to point at the location of your config file:

export OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/my/openssl.cnf

This way you can make changes without having to impact your entire system.
```

I used the second choice "export OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/my/openssl.cnf" and worked perfectly!

Comment: I hope that none of these servers and clients are visible to the internet. Lowering the TLS version is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this issue for about 10 hours. After typing a very detailed question, Stack Overflow showed me yours.

Comment: @felipewind you should mark your own answer as an accepted one to show others that your problem has been solved. Thank you for this post and solution!

Comment: How to force reload of that conf'??

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, for some reason I needed to do this _and_ update `openssl`.  I followed these instructions: https://fedingo.com/how-to-install-openssl-in-ubuntu/ but replaced `1.1.1c` with (the current latest version) `1.1.1m`.

Answer (score 9):

The solution that worked for me was to create an `openssl_tls1.cnf` containing:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Then setting `OPENSSL_CONF=/path/to/openssl_tls1.cnf` allows connecting with the lower protocol, as in

```
OPENSSL_CONF=openssl_tls1.cnf wget https://foo.bar
```

Comment: I was having trouble figuring out what to put where to use Felipe's answer. I couldn't edit or comment on his answer so I'm adding my own to hopefully help someone else.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation will help indeed.

Comment: That was it! In my case, the error started occurring when specifiying a JupyterHub Docker image beyond 1.1.1 (which still uses the older openssl 1.1.1, which doesn't need this) and the cause turns out to be the same. Thanks for putting an end to hours of debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Server supports TLSv1 and not TLSv1.1 and above

Ubuntu 20.x openssl version does not support TLSv1 and below.

**It could be that the openssl.cnf file has been updated to add a more secure connection defaults. It depends on the OS and the flavor.**

***Determine the location of the configuration file (for openssl for your flavor of linux) and figure out if there are any restrictions on lowering the TLS versions or what it is setup to by default.***

Try the following to see if the server supports TLSv1.1 and above:

```
 nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 your_host_name
```

Check the output to see the ciphers and the corresponding versions.

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
| TLSv1.0:
| ciphers:
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
| compressors:
| NULL
| TLSv1.1:
| ciphers:
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
| TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
```

Comment: I did the test, it seems it's only TLSv1. 
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-02 22:07 -03
Nmap scan report for my.domain (999.999.999.999)
Host is up (0.019s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
9023/tcp open  swa-1
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       Forward Secrecy not supported by any cipher
|_  least strength: A

Comment: Makes sense. And it seems that the openssl.cnf update did the trick.

Comment: They are not just defaults - I've found no way to override them on the command line. `openssl s_client -tls1` doesn't complain but silently refuses to actually use TLS 1.0. At least, I didn't gather that it does from the messages it returns.

Answer (score 1):

If you get error 14187180 like I did after trying the above answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level (or otherwise) you might like to try the --dtls-ciphers=LEGACY with openconnect.  I needed to both downgrade to TLSv1.1 as above (MinProtocol = TLSv1.1) and add this to connect to a customer's Cisco Anyconnect VPN.

```
echo password | OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/openssl_tls_1_0.cnf openconnect -v -g VPNGROUP -u username --dtls-ciphers=LEGACY --passwd-on-stdin vpn.domain
```

Answer (score 0):

For bare openssl, it might be simpler to use the cipher string directly instead of setting `OPENSSL_CONF`:

```bash
openssl s_client -cipher DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1 -tls1 -connect $host:$port
```