# IntelliJ Subversion Check out from sub version issue

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I am very new to Intellij and svn environment. I have tried to connect IntelliJ and SVN on MAC os. I have provided user name and password but IntelliJ Subversion Authentication Required Dialog box is **continuously** popping up. Credentials do not seem to be applied.  When I am trying to cancel it and check out I am getting an error message as follows:

Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://topicsvn.flinders.edu.au/svn-repos/COMP8741/jaya0232' svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication

What can I do for this issue?

I have tried the following solution without success:

- Provided user name and password several times
- Cleared the authentication cache from the Intellij subversion settings.
- Uninstalled and installed intellij again

Comment: Can you please check the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201289/cant-do-svn-checkout-because-of-tls-error